# Groovy xml edit value causes duplicate

Tags: xml, groovy

With more than a little help from daviderossi.blogspot.com I have managed to get some code working to replace an xml value with another 
This give me the following output which both edits the value at the 'ix' position BUT also adds a second copy at the end. If I search for it with LastIndexOf and delete it then it deletes the first occurrence. Any ideas on why the code might be doing that, or how to mitigate this unwanted effect??

```
def fm_xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MAlong>
<Enquiry.ID>SC11147</Enquiry.ID>
<student.name_middle></student.name_middle>
<student.name_known></student.name_known>
<student.name_previous></student.name_previous>
<student.name_cert>John REnfrew</student.name_cert>
<student.detail_gender>M</student.detail_gender>
<student.sign_name>John Renfrew</student.sign_name>
<student.sign_date>05/01/2010</student.sign_date>
</MAlong>'''

xml = new XmlParser().parseText(fm_xml)
ix = xml.children().findIndexOf{it.name() =='student.name_middle'}
nn = new Node(xml, 'student.name_middle', "NEW")
if (ix != -1 ) {
xml.children()[ix] = nn
nn.parent = xml
}
writer = new StringWriter()
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(xml)
result = writer.toString()
```

RESULT

```
<MAlong>
<Enquiry.ID>
 SC11147
</Enquiry.ID>
<student.name_middle>
 NEW
</student.name_middle>
<student.name_known/>
<student.name_previous/>
<student.name_cert>
 John REnfrew
</student.name_cert>
<student.detail_gender>
 M
</student.detail_gender>
<student.sign_name>
 John Renfrew
</student.sign_name>
<student.sign_date>
 05/01/2010
</student.sign_date>
<student.name_middle>
 NEW
</student.name_middle>
</MAlong>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Groovy class [XMLSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) to work with your XML makes your code easier and improves readability. I created a sample script at the Groovy Console where you can evaluate this:

- http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/177001 (first version)
- http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/180001 (with pretty print)

**Example-Code**

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def prettyprint(xml) {
  XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield xml })
}

def input = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MAlong>
<Enquiry.ID>SC11147</Enquiry.ID>
<student.name_middle></student.name_middle>
<student.name_known></student.name_known>
<student.name_previous></student.name_previous>
<student.name_cert>John REnfrew</student.name_cert>
<student.detail_gender>M</student.detail_gender>
<student.sign_name>John Renfrew</student.sign_name>
<student.sign_date>05/01/2010</student.sign_date>
</MAlong>'''

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)
println "Input\n" + prettyprint(root)

// static way
root.'student.name_middle' = "MIDDLE NAME"

// variable way
root.setProperty("student.name_previous", "PREVIOUS NAME")

println "Output\n" + prettyprint(root​)​
```

​
**Reference:**

- http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html
- http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/xml/StreamingMarkupBuilder.html

Comment: neater, much easier to read, but it throws an error:
[student.name_middle] is a constant expression, but it should be a variable expression

Would like to explore this as it seems very efficient.<br/>
Fixed the repeating values by making it
nn = new Node(null, 'student.name_middle', "NEW")

Comment: The above script should work as it is. I added a second modification statement showing modification of fields with dynamic names.

Comment: The output from that produces a single line. Is there a way to recreate the tree with markupbuilder??

Comment: Yes, you can do it this way: `println XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield root })​` and remember to `import groovy.xml.XmlUtil`